# Stop receiving all ActionEvents/Stop Listening in Java for a period of time?

Tags: java, swing

I have a simple program that utilizes Java Swing Timer to display an image for 400 miliseconds, in this period of time I just want to stop all ActionListeners or stop taking ActionEvents. I've got 40+ buttons and want a simple way to do this.

Is there anyway to do that in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you determine that you are in this "image displayed" state?  The image goes up and you set the state to "image displayed" or whatever.  Go through your widgets and decide which ones are supposed to be dead while the image is up.  Turn them into Observers of this state value.  When the state changes, they either enable or disable, as appropriate.  The image code doesn't do anything directly to any widget.  It just declares that the state is now "image displayed".  It's up to the Observers to decide what to do, if anything, with that information.

Or use the GlassPane.  That works too.  Of course, the GlassPane shuts down *everything*.  If you need to be more selective, you need a more fine-tuned approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a temporary `GlassPane` instance to consume all events by registering empty listeners to it.

Answer (score 1):

Use an undecorated modal JDialog to display the image. Before you make the dialog visible you would start a Timer. When the Timer fires in 400 ms you close the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar issues and typically found that its a design issue that got me in that situation.  Being the case, I still had to find away around it.  To fix the issue, I kept a list of the elements that I wanted to disable (stop listening) and iterated through them at the beginning and end of the timer.  For buttons it should be as simple as:

```
for(Component c : listOfToggledComponents){
     c.setEnabled(shouldItBeEnabled);
}
```

For buttons, this will grey out the button.  Similar things happen to other swing components.

Comment: I do not recommend this solution.

Comment: Perhaps an explanation as to why could be beneficial to the OP and myself.  However, I like Steve J's suggestion as well, although it is a similar iterative approach.